Caching requirements on dev containers for possible rebuilds
I am working with a project that has several containers being managed by Docker Compose. I realized that was easier to make VS Code editor connect to these containers to make features like auto-complete to work properly.
The problem is that every now and then I need to force those containers to be recreated which I noticed makes the container re-download some packages that VS Code requires.
Is there a way to cache these packages locally?
I know that we can create "volumes" through Docker Compose but I don't know which paths I should be using.
Maybe the VS Code plugin (dev containers) have a cache configuration that I don't know of?
